# Math.POW(x,y) getting different value from x ^ y

Tags: c#, javascript

In JavaScript

```
215 ^ 150 = 65
```

But when i try `Math.POW(215, 150)` in C# I am getting Infinite

Why it is not `65` ? How should I get 65 in C# ?

Comment: in javascript `Math.pow(215, 150) == Infinity`, where did you get 65 from?

Comment: you can try on 215 ^ 150  it will give 65 in javascript

Comment: @abccba because you're not using the same operation in C# and JavaScript ( in JS I think you're using XOR)

Comment: `Math.Pow` means 215 to the power of 150 which is the same as 215 ^ 215 on a calculator. I don't know what ^ does in javaScript but it looks like it does something like `Math.Abs(215 - 150)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are forgetting that the `^` operator is not a to-the power-of operator, but rather a bitwise XOR.

```
11010111 (215)
10010110 (150)  XOR
--------
01000001 (65)
```

215 to the power of 150 is obscenely large, hence the Infinite.

If you wanted the 65, then use `215 ^ 150`. However, if you wanted the 215 to the power of 150, then you're going to need to use a much bigger number variable type that `Math.POW(x,y)` can support. I'm not even sure if the [BigInteger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class) library can handle an operation of that magnitude, but it's worth a try if that is what you are after.

Answer (score 5):

Use the same syntax. `215 ^ 150` is really 65 in c#.

`^` means XOR (both in Javascript and c#) not Math.Pow(x,y)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or